# Passing argument from PHP to Python not working

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi, parameter-passing

I have a python srcipt, called rainbow.py. I can run it optionally with an argument. From command line
`python rainbow.py`,    `python rainbow.py 4`  works well. When I call this script from php I am unable to pass the argument.
I tried:

```
$argument=4; 
exec("python rainbow.py 4");
exec("python rainbow.py $argument");
exec("python rainboy.py .$argument");
```

They make the code run like there's no valid argument. (I use `duration=int(sys.argv[1]` in my python code, the script needs to stop after a while, and when calling from php, always the default duration is active)
I tried

`$argument="4"`

too, did not work.
Can you tell me what's wrong?How can I pass this argument through? I am confident with python, but a total php newbie.

part of my php code:

```
$argument="2";
echo "printing line  <br>";

exec("python rainbow.py $argument");//duration option does not work
```

part of my python code:

```
duration=10

try:
    if sys.argv[1]!=None:
        print "arg found!"

        duration=int(sys.argv[1])
except: pass
print "duration:",duration
```

I cant see the duration printing out when calling python from php, but from LEDs I can cleary see the duration is always 10 seconds

Comment: Are you positive that the second call to exec in your code example doesn't work?

Comment: Yes I am positive.

Answer (score 0):

I added sudo to the python call:

```
exec("sudo python rainbow.py $argument")
```

and it works now properly. Can someone tell me why?
The python script ran without it too, but without considering the argument.